# Python - Pivot Table : Count the Occurrence of Value based on the Last Index

Tags: python, indexing, count, pivot, pivot-table

could you help me how I can count the occurence of the last index in pivot table?

Raw data
[image]

```
Here is my code -- but the last column is returning me the Grand Total - based on the 1st index (A)

df.pivot_table(index=['A','B','C','D,'E','F','G'] 
                        , aggfunc={'G' : ['count',len]})
```

This should be the result (last column) once pivoted
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected count for column 'G', I included columns 'A'-'D' as indices and count of 'G' as follows:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A','B','C','D'],values='G',aggfunc={'G': ['count']})
```

Here is the resulting pivot table, where the expected count is shown:

[image: pivot table]

If however we include all columns as indices, the count of 'G' stays at 1.

Creating a similar pivot table with all columns in Excel shows an identical behaviour with only count of 1's:

[image: pivot table in Excel]